# Multiple Subqueries and Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I have a subquery which does the following;

```
Select
    Min(S_Date)
,   Col1
,   Col2
From 
(
    Select Dateadd(whatever) as S_Date, Userid 
    from tbl1 as t 
    where S_Date >'today'
)
```

How can I add another clause so that value from Col1 is only selected if another condition is met, i.e col3 = 'doit'. I guess I am trouble understanding how to use two where clauses in different places in a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    s_date
    ,CASE Col3 WHEN 'doit' THEN Col1 ELSE Col2 END AS selection
FROM (
    SELECT 
       Sdate
       , Col1
       , Col2
       , Col3
    FROM foo
    WHERE s_Date > GETDATE()
 ) AS sub
```

Comment: I edit my original question, as I forgot to put the important part, which is that I want the Min(date). I have tried using a case, but then if the condition isnt met, it gives me a null, when I really want to take the min(date) of the first 'doit'.

Comment: Can you post the entire query that you're working with? It looks as if you need to do the min(date) within the subquery and then use the CASE statement in the outer query on those results.

Answer (score 1):

To use aggregate functions like MIN() you need to group by the columns you're not aggregating...

```
Select
  Min(S_Date)
, Col1
, Col2
From 
  (
    Select Dateadd(whatever) as S_Date, Userid 
    from tbl1 as t 
    where S_Date >'today'
  )
GROUP BY
  Col1,
  Col2
```

If you then want the non-aggregated columns to be conditional, you again group by those conditional values...

```
Select
  Min(S_Date)
, CASE WHEN col3 = 'doit' THEN Col1 ELSE Col2 END AS conditional_field
From 
  (
    Select Dateadd(whatever) as S_Date, Userid 
    from tbl1 as t 
    where S_Date >'today'
  )
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN col3 = 'doit' THEN Col1 ELSE Col2 END
```

I'm not 100% sure what you actually want to achieve though.  Do you have a sample set of data, with the results you want, and an explanation of how the results relate to the source?